# Scroll down to selected option on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of countries like this:

[image: screenshot]

The list is very extensive. I need to be able on a button click to move (focus) to the specified country.

There are many threads in StackOverflow but none of them worked. For example I tried this:

```
var code = 40;
$('#id_resource-regions').val(code).scrollTop(160);
```

There is no response and no error/warnings in the developers tool.
Note that the list is created using django forms and templates.

Comment: The code you tried has no sense under the HTML you show. There's no element with id `s`. The select id is `id_resource-regions`. As a developer tip, when you copypaste something, try to read each line and understand the meaning of every piece of it. That way you won't lose your mind with small things like this.

Comment: @Jorge Fuentes González  thanks mate. Ofcource I have changed the id of the element. I just forgot to correct this in the code above. The issue is still there.

Comment: Try to add a `console.log("test")` just before the `scrollTop` line to see if the code is reaching it. Maybe is not called. By the way, `scrollTop(160)` will not fit all the values as each one is in a different height. You should use `.offset().top` of the element you want to scroll to. Add a working fiddle so we will be able to help you better.

Comment: You have a select and options which button you mean ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Select the `option` element you are looking for.
- Get the offset top position using [**.offset()**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), of the selected option element.
- Get the offset top of the select element.
- Use [**.scrollTop()**](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to scroll to the desired option.

Here is an example

```js
var btn = $('button')
var select = $('select')

btn.on('click', function() {
  var option = select.find("option:contains('item-30')");
  var optionTop = option.offset().top
  var selectTop = select.offset().top;
  select.scrollTop(select.scrollTop() + (optionTop - selectTop));
  option.prop('selected', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="" id="select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">item-1</option>
  <option value="">item-2</option>
  <option value="">item-3</option>
  <option value="">item-4</option>
  <option value="">item-5</option>
  <option value="">item-6</option>
  <option value="">item-7</option>
  <option value="">item-8</option>
  <option value="">item-9</option>
  <option value="">item-10</option>
  <option value="">item-11</option>
  <option value="">item-12</option>
  <option value="">item-13</option>
  <option value="">item-14</option>
  <option value="">item-15</option>
  <option value="">item-16</option>
  <option value="">item-17</option>
  <option value="">item-18</option>
  <option value="">item-19</option>
  <option value="">item-20</option>
  <option value="">item-21</option>
  <option value="">item-22</option>
  <option value="">item-23</option>
  <option value="">item-24</option>
  <option value="">item-25</option>
  <option value="">item-26</option>
  <option value="">item-27</option>
  <option value="">item-28</option>
  <option value="">item-29</option>
  <option value="">item-30</option>
  <option value="">item-31</option>
  <option value="">item-32</option>
  <option value="">item-33</option>
  <option value="">item-34</option>
  <option value="">item-35</option>
  <option value="">item-36</option>
  <option value="">item-37</option>
  <option value="">item-38</option>
  <option value="">item-39</option>
  <option value="">item-40</option>
</select>

<button>move to item 30</button>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly the answer I was looking for, but I encountered two hiccups and I'm sure that if I did someone else did too.

It's worth noting that I have a collapsing select element with only one option permissible. 

a) my option.offset().top is always 0, no matter which options is selected
b) when I apply the scrollTop with any value, my select list doesn't seem to move at all